# Increase gas_limit for tz1 to tz1 transfers

Tags: fees, gas

Can `15400` KT gas limit be used as upper limit also for pkh2pkh txs (instead of `10600`) or there's risk to incur in some kind of error?

For pkh2pkh I mean a transfer from tz1 to tz1 address.
For pkh2kt I mean a transfer from tz1 to KT1 address.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the gas limit to whatever you want. Say 20000. Tezos will only consume however much it needs. If it only needs 5000, then it'll only consume 5000, not 20000.

Comment: @Rocco Please mark answered if all good